# How to make an input allows html tags in wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a wordpress website and used plugin called '`WooCommerce Product Subtitle`' to add text under the title.

But the input didn't allow html tags.

How can I make that input allow html tags?

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: Hello, Please check my updated answer.

Comment: I got the solutions for your questions,for that you have to change one function line in plugin files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TO make input allow html tags, I have done with one line of code in plugin file.
see this screenshot: https://www.screencast.com/t/AUGvfS8lyRg

Path : wp-content\plugins\wc-product-subtitle\includes\class-admin-handler.php
Line No : 58

****just replace below line with line no 58:****

### Before

update_post_meta( $post_id, WCPS_DB.'subtitle', wp_kses( $_POST['product_subtitle'],array() ) );

### After

update_post_meta( $post_id, WCPS_DB.'subtitle', wp_kses_post( $_POST['product_subtitle'],array() ) );

Hop this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Updated code:

Edit single product template and display the field's value

```
<?php 
global $post;
$subtitle =  get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wc_ps_subtitle', true );
echo '<div style="font-size:26px;">'.$subtitle.'</div>';
?>
```

You can get subtitle from above code and manage  HTML tag also.

Hop this works for you.

Comment: Hello PPL , thank you ,
look at that https://imgur.com/sCL7PGV 
i need to make that input allow html tags , in page product , when i save the input not compile the html tags and appear it as a text

Comment: thanks but i need the input allow html tags to put custom style per product